# Validating integer field with custom model binder in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I ran into an issue that I thought was interesting.

Take an input form that has an input field for an integer value (cost, in my case).  I do not want "$100" or "Twenty Dollars" to be sent to the database as it will likely complain.  I want to add an error to the model and send it back to the user.  Seemed simple ;).

I am using a custom model binder because I am using some inheritance in my domain model.  I have multiple types of events, each type implementing IEvent - thus, I needed a custom model binder.

***The issue I have is, when I am trying to bind the cost field, and the conversion from string to int fails, I am really not sure how best to handle this.***

My Custom Model Binder
    public class EventModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        #region IModelBinder Members

```
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        // Trivial code ... binding other fields...

        _event.ProjectedCost = GetA<int>(bindingContext, "ProjectedCost").GetValueOrDefault(-1);

        return _event;
    }

    #endregion

    // From Scott Hanselman's blog :)
    private Nullable<T> GetA<T>(ModelBindingContext bindingContext, string key) where T : struct
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(key)) return null;
        ValueProviderResult valueResult;
        Nullable<T> ret;
        //Try it with the prefix...
        bindingContext.ValueProvider.TryGetValue(bindingContext.ModelName + "." + key, out valueResult);
        //Didn't work? Try without the prefix if needed...
        if (valueResult == null && bindingContext.FallbackToEmptyPrefix == true)
        {
            bindingContext.ValueProvider.TryGetValue(key, out valueResult);
        }
        if (valueResult == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        try
        {
            ret = (Nullable<T>)valueResult.ConvertTo(typeof(T));
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

This works really well - if Enums are null or not selected, I can validate against them and let the user know it is required.  For the cost field, I get -1 if the conversion failed.  But, when I go to validate the data on the server and go back to the UI, the Model.Event.ProjectedCost field is null

My EventService

```
// ...
protected bool ValidateEvent(IEvent eventToValidate)
    {            
        if (eventToValidate.ProjectedCost < 0)
            _validationDictionary.AddError("ProjectedCost", "Incorrect format");

        return _validationDictionary.IsValid;
    }

    public bool SaveEvent(IEvent _event)
    {
        if (!ValidateEvent(_event))
            return false;
        try
        {
            _repository.SaveEvent(_event);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
```

My Edit.aspx View

```
<h2>Edit</h2>

<%= Html.ValidationSummary("Edit was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.") %>

<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fields</legend>
        <p>
            <label for="ProjectedCost">ProjectedCost:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("ProjectedCost", Model.Event.ProjectedCost) %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("ProjectedCost", "*") %>
        </p>

        <% Html.RenderPartial(String.Format("~/Views/Shared/{0}Form.ascx", Model.Event.Type), Model.Event, ViewData); %>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>

<% } %>

<div>
    <%=Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") %>
</div>
```

In my view, Model.Event.ProjectedCost is null if it doesn't validate, giving me this (Line 54 is the culprit):

```
Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

Line 52:             <p>
Line 53:                 <label for="ProjectedCost">ProjectedCost:</label>
Line 54:                 <%= Html.TextBox("ProjectedCost", (Model.Event.ProjectedCost == null ? 0 : Model.Event.ProjectedCost)) %>
Line 55:                 <%= Html.ValidationMessage("ProjectedCost", "*") %>
Line 56:             </p>
```

What I'd kind of like to do is send the value the user entered back to the user, but my custom model binder and/or validation logic seems to be setting something to null?

I realize this may  not be the easiest question to read, so let me know if I can clarify in any way!

Comment: Are you sure you can't use the default model binder? Coz i suspect that the binder is not doing something the default one does and that's why your value is not being returned on validation

Comment: I tried, but my views inherit from IEvent - so the default model binder tried to create an instance of IEvent, which isn't possible as it is an interface.

Answer (score 1):

You could use javascript to restrict the input of the the textbox to just integers.

Comment: +1 Very true - I'd like to not rely soley on JS, however.  I want to have a solid fall-back in case the user disables JS

Comment: Yea, definitely.  I would never have just front end validation, because you never know how the user is set up

Answer (score 0):

Seems that if you call AddModelError without SetModelValue first, you'll get a shiny-new NullReferenceExceptions sometimes:

http://www.crankingoutcode.com/?aspxerrorpath=/2009/02/01/IssuesWithAddModelErrorSetModelValueWithMVCRC1.aspx

Comment: That blog post fixed it, but now I get "-1" for the value, and not the value the user entered.  Hmm..